# How To Hide Tkinter python Gui

Tags: python, tkinter

anyone know how to hide python GUI Tkinter, 
I 've created keylogger, for GUI I used python module Tkinter , I want to add button called HIDE, so when user click it it will  hide GUI , and when user press key like CTRL+E , it should unhide GUI....?

Comment: When the window is hidden it won't receive any keyboard or mouse events. Are you aware of that? It can only log keys pressed in the tkinter window.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To hide the default root window you can use

```
root.withdraw()
```

and to make it visible again you can use

```
root.deiconify()
```

Comment: I tried to add root.withdraw() exitButtonPushed(), instead root.destroy() , but it wont work , see code above

Comment: thx, I will try another way , I will run keylogger.py when user click RUN , and when uses click HIDE it will exit from gui, but keylogger.py will stay running

Answer (score 4):

Python 3:

```
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "hide" the window (NOT destroy it) and bring it back, then the way to do that is set the alpha channel.

To hide the window, set the alpha channel to 0:

```
master.attributes('-alpha', 0)
```

to restore the window set alpha to 1.0:

```
master.attributes('-alpha', 1.0)
```

[EDIT - had the incorrect type/range for the original answer. Range is 0 to 1.0 and is a float]

Comment: This isn’t supported on all systems; where not supported, Tkinter always uses **1.0**. [alpha](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.attributes-method)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yea, I blew that answer originally.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of a GUI window I used the following in my code.

window.destroy()

and the following to bring it up again.

*nameoffunction*()
window.lift()

Comment: `window.destroy` does nothing. If you want to call the destroy method you must include parenthesis: `window.destroy()`. If you call that on the root window, the program will exit.