# can't place frame inside a toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to place a frame with a bunch of widgets inside a toplevel window for which I have created menus. When I run the program I get two separate windows (see screen grab).

What I want is to see the labels, entry boxes, buttons, etc. inside the larger "main" window.

[Screenshot of actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0e49.png)

Here is the code:

```
# Basic menubar with a few sub-menus

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()

root.option_add("tearOff", FALSE)

# ***************  SETUP THE CONTAINERS ***********
root.title("Menu Example")
root.geometry("600x300")

#frame = ttk.Frame(root, borderwidth = 5, relief = "sunken")

#frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = (N,W,E,S))

# ***************************************************

# ****  Create the Menubar
win = Toplevel(root)
menubar = Menu(win)

appmenu = Menu(menubar, name='apple')


menubar.add_cascade(menu=appmenu)
appmenu.add_command(label='About My Application')
appmenu.add_separator()


win["menu"]=menubar

# Add some menus to the menubar
menu_file = Menu(menubar)
menu_edit = Menu(menubar)
menu_transform = Menu(menubar)

menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_file, label="File") # cascade menu items add a menu to a menubar
menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_edit, label="Edit")

# Add items to the menus
menu_file.add_command(label = "New") # command menu items add commands to a menu.
menu_file.add_command(label = "Open...")
menu_file.add_command(label = "Close")
menu_file.add_separator()
menu_file.add_command(label = "Export as ...")


menu_edit.add_command(label = "Copy")
menu_edit.add_command(label = "Paste")
menu_edit.add_cascade(menu=menu_transform, label="Transform")
menu_transform.add_command(label="group")
menu_transform.add_command(label="ungroup")
menu_transform.add_command(label="align")


#menu_edit.add_command(label = "Transform")




# *****************************************
frame = ttk.Frame(win, borderwidth = 5, relief = "sunken")
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = (N,W,E,S))

# ***************************************************

ipaddr = StringVar()
username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()

ipAddrLbl = ttk.Label(frame, text="Switch IP Address:")
ipAddrLbl.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky = W)

usernameLbl = ttk.Label(frame, text="User Name:")
usernameLbl.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky = W)

passwordLbl = ttk.Label(frame, text="Password:")
passwordLbl.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky = W)

ipaddrEntry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable="ipaddr")
ipaddrEntry.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky = W)

usernameEntry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable="username")
usernameEntry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky = W)

passwordEntry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable="password", show = "*")
passwordEntry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky = W)

loginButton = ttk.Button(frame, text = "Login")
loginButton.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=W)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why not using the `root` widget directly ? do you have multiple Toplevel to handle here ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. First you say you want the widgets in a toplevel, then you say you want them in the "main" window. Which is it? They are currently going in the toplevel.

Comment: What then is the second, larger window?  Where is that coming from and how do i get rid of it?

Comment: The other larger window is the root window (ie: the result of  `root = Tk()`)

Comment: I think what you really want to ask is [How To Hide Tkinter python Gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764927/how-to-hide-tkinter-python-gui)

Comment: Bryan, thanks!!  getting rid of the "win" widget and putting everything in root did the trick.

Comment: Just want to add that `Toplevel` is normally used to create a new window if one is needed outside of the root/main window.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer for this question is to iconify the root window, then you can tinker with the Toplevel to your hearts content. That way, the root main window is hidden while the mainloop is still going without dual tkinter instances. Heres the edited code with a little tweaking so that the mainloop stops when the Toplevel is closed.

```
# Basic menubar with a few sub-menus

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def _delete_window():
    print ("delete_window")
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:
        pass

root = Tk()

root.option_add("tearOff", FALSE)

# ***************  SETUP THE CONTAINERS ***********
root.title("Menu Example")
root.geometry("600x300")
root.iconify()
#frame = ttk.Frame(root, borderwidth = 5, relief = "sunken")

#frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = (N,W,E,S))

# ***************************************************

# ****  Create the Menubar
win = Toplevel(root)
win.geometry('400x150')
menubar = Menu(win)

appmenu = Menu(menubar, name='apple')


menubar.add_cascade(menu=appmenu)
appmenu.add_command(label='About My Application')
appmenu.add_separator()


win["menu"]=menubar

# Add some menus to the menubar
menu_file = Menu(menubar)
menu_edit = Menu(menubar)
menu_transform = Menu(menubar)

menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_file, label="File") # cascade menu items add a menu to 
a menubar
menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_edit, label="Edit")

# Add items to the menus
menu_file.add_command(label = "New") # command menu items add commands to a menu.
menu_file.add_command(label = "Open...")
menu_file.add_command(label = "Close")
menu_file.add_separator()
menu_file.add_command(label = "Export as ...")


menu_edit.add_command(label = "Copy")
menu_edit.add_command(label = "Paste")
menu_edit.add_cascade(menu=menu_transform, label="Transform")
menu_transform.add_command(label="group")
menu_transform.add_command(label="ungroup")
menu_transform.add_command(label="align")


#menu_edit.add_command(label = "Transform")




# *****************************************
frame = Frame(win, borderwidth = 5, relief = "sunken")
frame.pack()
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
# ***************************************************

ipaddr = StringVar()
username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()

ipAddrLbl = ttk.Label(frame, text="Switch IP Address:")
ipAddrLbl.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky = W)

usernameLbl = ttk.Label(frame, text="User Name:")
usernameLbl.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky = W)

passwordLbl = ttk.Label(frame, text="Password:")
passwordLbl.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky = W)

ipaddrEntry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable="ipaddr")
ipaddrEntry.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky = W)

usernameEntry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable="username")
usernameEntry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky = W)

passwordEntry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable="password", show = "*")
passwordEntry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky = W)

loginButton = ttk.Button(frame, text = "Login")
loginButton.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=W)

win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", _delete_window)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Corrected code to use Toplevel widget instead of new Tk instance:

```
import tkinter as tk
class Gui1:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.frame = tk.Frame(root)
        self.button =  tk.Button(text="Openwindow2",
        command=self.create_gui2)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.frame.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def create_gui2(self):
        class Gui2:
            def __init__(self, root2):
                self.root2 = root2
                self.frame2 = tk.Frame(root2)
                self.label=tk.Label(text="Window 2")
                self.label.grid(row=0,column=0)
                self.frame2.grid(row=3,column=3)

        root2 = tk.Toplevel()
        app2 = Gui2(root2)


root = tk.Tk()
app = Gui1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should not be creating more than one instance of `Tk`. It doesn't matter whether it's nested or not.

Comment: If you need more than one window, the second and subsequent windows need to be instances of `Toplevel`. A tkinter application should almost always have precisely one instance of `Tk`.

Comment: So do I just replace the second Tk instance with Toplevel?  I don't see any difference in my application.

Comment: You may not see a difference if you have a small, somewhat uncomplicated application. There is indeed a difference though. Every time you create a new instance of `Tk` you get a new embedded tcl interpreter with its own namespace, This means that widgets and variables (`StringVar`, etc) and bindings won't be accessible from one to the other.